# Local variables from main are modified by others programs' functions, even though it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope

I've got an error in python trying to do my homework for python course. The task was to create an array of expenses using operations such as add and list(printing all the elements)

The error persists in any version of Python (3.7,3.8,3.9) and in different IDEs ( Visual Studio, PyCharm, some online interpretator)

To describe the error:
Variables from main function are modified by auxiliary functions, even though there is no handler to modify that data. I suppose that the program considers variables from main function as global.

I am real newbie in python, so it's possible that I just didn't understand some basic concepts of the language.

This is the code (I know I shouldn't post the whole code, but I have no ideea where does the error comes from):

```
from datetime import date

def get_day_of_expense(_element):
    return int(_element['day'])


def get_type_of_expense(_element):
    return _element['expense type']


def get_amount_of_money_of_expense(_element):
    return int(_element['amount of money'])


def function_add_a_new_expense(expenses_table, _expense_type, _day, _amount_of_money):
    expenses_table.append({'day': _day, 'expense type': _expense_type, 'amount of money': _amount_of_money})
    return expenses_table


def check_for_expense_type(expenses_table_types, _expense_type):
    '''
    This function check if the searched _expense_type is a valid one (exists in array of types)
    :param: expenses_table_types: array of expense types
    :pram: _expense_type: the searched value type
    :return: True if the element was found, False otherwise
    '''
    for expense_type in expenses_table_types:
        if _expense_type == expense_type:
            return True
    return False


def check_for_command(command_dictionary, _command_name):
    '''
    This function check if the searched command is a valid one (exists in array of commands)
    :param: command_dictionary: dictionary of commands
    :pram: _command_name: the searched command
    :return: True if the element was found, False otherwise
    '''
    for command in command_dictionary.keys():
        if command == _command_name:
            return True
    return False


def finish_program(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, _data_array):
    return {'continue': False, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Goodbye"}


def get_today_date():
    return date.today().day


def initialize_command_dictionary():
    command_dictionary = {
        'add': {'description': "Add a new expense in current day : add <sum> <expense type>",
                'command': add_a_new_expense},
        'list': {
            'description': "Print all expenses : list", 'command': display_all_expenses_UI},
        'exit': {'description': 'Exit the program', 'command': finish_program}
    }
    return command_dictionary


def to_str(_expense):
    return 'Day: ' + str(get_day_of_expense(_expense)).rjust(2) + ', Expense type: ' + str(
        get_type_of_expense(_expense)).ljust(12) + ' > ' + str(get_amount_of_money_of_expense(_expense)).rjust(4)


def add_a_new_expense(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, _data_array):
    """
    This function handles the add command
    :param: expenses_table_types: array of expense types
    :param: expenses_table: the list of expenses
    :param: _data_array: the input command parsed by words [command,amount of money,expense_type]
    :return: a dictionary with properties continue ( True or False if the program should continue or not), updated expenses_table array and message, a string that can be a confirmation or an error
    """
    if (len(_data_array) < 3):
        return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Incomplete command"}
    elif len(_data_array) > 3:
        return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Command is too long"}
    else:
        try:
            _day = get_today_date()
        except:
            return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Could not query date correctly"}
        try:
            _amount_of_money = int(_data_array[1])
            if (_amount_of_money < 1):
                return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table,
                        'message': "Amount of money should be greater than 0"}
        except ValueError:
            return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Amount of money must be an integer"}
        expense_type = _data_array[2]
        if not check_for_expense_type(expenses_table_types, expense_type):
            return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "This expense type does not exist"}
        else:
            expenses_table = function_add_a_new_expense(expenses_table, expense_type, _day, _amount_of_money)
            return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Added the expense"}


def display_all_expenses_UI(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, command_split_in_words):
    """
    This function prints the array of expenses
    :param: expenses_table_types: array of expense types
    :param: expenses_table_types,command_split_in_words : 2 extra so I can call from command_dictionary
    :return: a dictionary with properties continue ( True or False if the program should continue or not), updated expenses_table array and message, a string that can be a confirmation or an error
    """
    for _expense in expenses_table:
        print(to_str(_expense))
    if len(expenses_table) == 0:
        return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "The selection of the list is null"}
    return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': ""}


def print_menu(command_dictionary):
    print(
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    for command in command_dictionary.keys():
        print(command + ": " + command_dictionary[command]['description'])


def command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, command):
    """
    This function takes the input, converts it into an array of words and calls the function needed
    :param: expenses_table_types: array of expense types
   :param: expenses_table: the list of expenses
   :param: command: input that was just read and waits to be parsed
   :return: a dictionary with properties continue ( True or False if the program should continue or not), updated expenses_table array and message, a string that can be a confirmation or an error

    """
    command_dictionary = initialize_command_dictionary()
    command_split_in_words = command.strip().split(' ')
    _command_name = command_split_in_words[0]
    if check_for_command(command_dictionary, _command_name):
        return command_dictionary[_command_name]['command'](expenses_table_types, expenses_table,
                                                            command_split_in_words)
    else:
        return {'continue': True, 'expenses_table': expenses_table, 'message': "Invalid command"}


def menu_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table):
    """
    This function ensure the user interface and reads the commands
    :param: expenses_table_types: array of expense types
    :param: expenses_table: the list of expenses
    :return: calls the function command_handler which will continue interpreting the command
    """
    command_dictionary = initialize_command_dictionary()
    print_menu(command_dictionary)
    command = input("Give a command: ")
    return command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, command)


def test_init(expenses_table_types, expenses_table):
    # use this function to add the 10 required items
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 25 clothing')
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 100 internet')
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 1230 others')
    display_all_expenses_UI(expenses_table_types, expenses_table,[])  # this prints the expenses_table with all those 3 elements previously added, even though I don't save the elements
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 15 transport')
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 50 food')
    command_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, 'add 30 housekeeping')
    add_a_new_expense(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, ['add', '50', 'housekeeping']) # this also does that weird behaviour. Item is added even though it shoulnd't
    print('------------------------------Second test output. This should not work---------------------------------')
    display_all_expenses_UI(expenses_table_types, expenses_table,[])

def main():
    expenses_table = []
    expenses_table_types = ['housekeeping', 'food', 'transport', 'clothing', 'internet', 'others']
    test_init(expenses_table_types, expenses_table)
    print('-----------------------------------Testing again in main. This should also not work---------------------------------------------')
    display_all_expenses_UI(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, [])
    _continue = True
    while _continue:
        _result = menu_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table)
        print(_result['message'])
        _continue = _result['continue']
        expenses_table = _result['expenses_table']
    '''
    This also works
    while _continue:
        menu_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table)
        display_all_expenses_UI(expenses_table_types, expenses_table, [])
    '''
    '''
    This also works
    while _continue:
        menu_handler(expenses_table_types, expenses_table)
        print(expenses_table) 
        
    just checked not to be a weird link between functions, to pass false data between them
    '''
main()
```

Comment: Variables in main are not global.  In Python, "main" is just another function name and has no special properties at all.  You say that other functions are modifying variables in main but that is simply not true.  It is NOT happening.  I don't know why you think that it is happening - you need to explain EXACTLY what you are seeing so we can figure out how you came to that (false) conclusion.  I see that one of your variables is a list and that you pass that list as an argument to another function. The other function can change what's in the list.  Is that what you think is the problem?

Comment: I didn't knew about the concepts of movable and immovable data types in python. Basic misunderstanding of the language :)) . Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change variables from another functions.

BUT! list is an OBJECT and you can change any objects from another function if ONLY you give the function a link to the object:

```
def function_1():
    variable_1 = 'Hello from function 1!'
    
    
def function_2(give_me_the_variable):
    give_me_the_variable = 'Hello from function 2!'


def function_3(give_me_link_to_the_object):
    give_me_link_to_the_object[0] = 'data from function_3'

    
def main():
    variable_1 = 'Hello from main!'
    print(variable_1)
  
    function_1()
    print('Variable is still: ' + variable_1)
   
    function_2(variable_1)
    print('Variable is still: ' + variable_1)

    test_list = ['main1', 'main2', 'main3']
    print('Data from list without changes: ' + str(test_list))

    function_3(test_list)
    print('Data from test_list after changing from function_3: ' + str(test_list))
    
    
main()
```

And the output will be:

```
Hello from main!

Variable is still: Hello from main!

Variable is still: Hello from main!

Data from list without changes: ['main1', 'main2', 'main3']

Data from test_list after changes from function_3: ['data from function_3', 'main2', 'main3']
```

You can convert your lists to tuples(unchangeble lists) and give them to your functions to be sure that you functions can't change data in your lists:

```
my_list = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)

print(type(my_tuple))
print(my_tuple)
```

And sory for my English:))

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem. Apparently I need to read more on this kind of data passing :))

Comment: You're welcome:) It all will come with experience, just move forward.

Comment: Hello.  Your answer is correct but it might be confusing.  Tuples are not changeable.  That is correct.  Strings are not changeable either.  When you use a string in a function call it cannot be changed by the function.  You call function_2 with a string argument so it will not change no matter what is in function_2.  Also, your function_2 will not change its argument no matter what type the argument is. It just reassigns the argument's object to a new local variable, which is then discarded.

Comment: Hello, TheXGeneral asked about why he could change local variables in another functions, I answered him about it - it's because he's using lists objects, objects are changeble. And then I taken him the idea to convert lists to tuples and use tuples like unchangeble objects. About strings - he didn't ask about it and it doesn't refer to main question.